# netlogo error cannot find element x in list of length x

Tags: netlogo

the below procedure is intended to select one "patron" out of a number of turtles and change their color to white. The selection is probabilistic based on the wealth of the turtles.

Running this code, specifically the line `item i ranking-in-radius` I get an error message something like this: "`cannot find element 43 in list...(shows list of turtles' wealth)... which is only of length 43.`" I understand I'm getting this error because lists start at 0, thus a list of 43 elements goes from 0 to 42, but I don't understand why the code I've written isn't correct for that. My `i` starts at `0`, and the procedure stops if `i` isn't `<` than the number of turtles queried (ie should stop at 42). Can anyone suggest a solution? Thanks!

```
to choose-patron
  let i 0
  let patrons-in-radius count turtles in-radius radius with [wealth >= 80]
  let ranking-in-radius sort-by > [wealth] of turtles in-radius radius with  [wealth >= 80]
  let total-wealth-in-radius sum [wealth] of turtles in-radius radius with [wealth >= 80]
  while [i < (patrons-in-radius)][
    ask turtles in-radius radius with [wealth >= 80] [
      if [wealth] of self = item i ranking-in-radius [   
        if random 100 < ((wealth / total-wealth-in-radius) * 100) [
          set color white
          if any? turtles in-radius radius with [color = white] [stop]
      ]
      set i (i + 1)
    ]
  ]
]
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `set i (i + 1)` is in the wrong block. Right now `i` increases every time your `if [wealth]...` runs, but you should only have `i` increase at the end of the `while [i < (patrons-in-radius)]` block.

Try the code below as a replacement for your `while` statement:

```
  while [ i < (patrons-in-radius) ] [
    ask turtles in-radius radius with [ wealth >= 80 ] [
      if [ wealth ] of self = item i ranking-in-radius [   
        if random 100 < ( (wealth / total-wealth-in-radius) * 100) [
          set color white
          if any? turtles in-radius radius with [color = white] [
            stop
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    set i i + 1
  ]
```